# Access viewController data from popOverView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

So let's say I have a `viewController` view and a popup `UITableView` table.

I want to be able to change the background view of the `viewController` that calls the pop-up table by selecting an option from the table.

**So what I want to do is the following:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    int selectedEntry = indexPath.row;
    switch(selectedEntry){
        case 1:
          //CODE TO CHANGE ORIGINAL VIEW TO IMAGE 1
        case 2:
          //CODE TO CHANGE ORIGINAL VIEW TO IMAGE 2
        //etc
   }
}
```

I already know that if I was writing the method directly in the base view class I could just write

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE"]];
```

but since it's being called from the popup menu, I don't know how to access it.

Comment: where are you writing this method..? In the same view controller or any other view controller..?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to add a property to your `UIViewController` in your `UITableView` subclass, so you can keep a reference to it, and access it afterwards:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyViewController *parentVC;
```

(`MyViewController` being your `UIViewController` subclass)

When you init your `UITableView` from your `UIViewController`, set its `parentVC` property to `self`. Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, use:

```
parentVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click button in popover controller, you can use a delegate to listen to the button action and do the needful in the view controller. OR you can use NSNotification to post notification during button click and listen to the notification in the view controller.

Write this in the button action

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIButtonOneClickedNotification object:nil];
```

Write this in the view controller didLoad method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonOneClicked:) name:UIButtonOneClickedNotification object:nil];
```

And do what you need to do in the method buttonOneClicked:

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NSNotificationCenter`.

Add this lines.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int selectedEntry = indexPath.row;
    switch(selectedEntry){
        case 1:
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeBackground" object:self userInfo:yourData1];
        case 2:
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeBackground" object:self userInfo:yourData2];
        //etc
   }
}
```

Add this to `BaseViewController` where you want to change background

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeBackgroundView:) name:@"ChangeBackground" object:nil];

}

- (void)changeBackgroundView:(NSNotification *)yourData {

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE"]];

}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what I should put in for "yourData". Would it just be the string with the image filename?

Comment: If I try do do           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeBackground" object:self userInfo:@"IMAGE1.png"]; Then when I call changeBackgroundView I'm unable to use "yourData" as the string for the filename.

Comment: Access it like this.
NSString *imageName = [yourData userInfo];

Comment: Instead of userinfo pass your string in "object" like this

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeBackground" object:@"IMAGE1.png" userInfo:nil];
and acess it as below.
NSString *imageName = [yourData object];

because userInfo only accept NSDictionary as a parameter.

You can pass any object in "object" and NSDictionary in "userInfo".
in the selector method just access it using
[yourData object];
and
[yourData userInfo];

Answer (score 0):

by using protocol you can do this like
like AVC(aViewController) show BVC(bviewcontroller) as popover then you need to do is as follows
in BVC.h

```
@protocol TablePopoverDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)doSomeWork;
@end
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TablePopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

and in BVC.m you need to do is

```
- (IBAction)buttoonpressd:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate doSomeWork];
}
```

and in AVC.h you need to add this protocol :"TablePopoverDelegate"

and then in AVC.m you need to implement desired function
and set delegate
like as follows

do this stuff from where you present popover

here "button" is a sender by pressing it you are going to show popover

```
__weak UIViewController *selfView = self;

UIViewController *nextViewController;
UIViewController *infoViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            infoViewController.delegate = self;
            nextViewController = infoViewController;


_popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nextViewController];
        [self.popOverController setDelegate:self];
        __weak UIPopoverController *blockPopoverController = self.popOverController;

        self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock = ^(void){
            [blockPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button convertRect:button.bounds toView:selfView.view]
                                                    inView:selfView.view
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                  animated:YES];
        };
        // invoke the presentation block to show the popover now
        self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock();
```

and here is the function you are calling by delegate

```
-(void)doSomeWork
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```